# Any reason to use Environment.NewLine instead of \n in XF code for an iOS or Android mobile device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's an example of my code:

```cs
Shell.Current.DisplayAlert($"Stop Quiz {Settings.Quiz}",
       $"{Environment.NewLine}You tapped the {target} icon " +
       $"at the bottom of this page. The quiz will be stopped " +
       $"and you will be taken to the {target} screen." +
       $"{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}" +
       $"Please confirm{Environment.NewLine}", 
       "OK", "Cancel") == true)
```

What I am wondering, is why use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `backslash n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the platform. On Windows it is actually "\r\n".

From MSDN:

> A string containing "\r\n" for
>   non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.NewLine` will return `\n` for Unix systems and `\r\n` for Windows, making your code platform independent.

.Net Core implementation:

```cs
public static String NewLine {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() != null);
#if !PLATFORM_UNIX
        return "\r\n";
#else
        return "\n";
#endif // !PLATFORM_UNIX
    }
}
```

Comment: For a XF app that only targets iOS and Android then would  \n be the same then?

Comment: Correct. I would argue that using `Environment.NewLine` is the better choice, as it will ensure you're always using the proper newline sequence for the environment you're compiling for.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of a Xamarin Forms app, there is effectively no difference between `Environment.NewLine` and `\n` (and in fact, many interpreters on windows will convert `\n` to `\r\n` automatically).

However, here are my reasons for preferring `Environment.NewLine`:

- It shows intent.  Sure, you can write `\n` and everyone *should* know it means newline.  However, `Environment.NewLine` shows clearly what the developer wants the code to do and it will return the correct implementation for the platform it's running under.
- It provides some degree of future-proofing.  Hypothetically, if .Net were to add support for an operating system which uses a *different* character to represent newline, then the developer might need to update all existing code to handle this case.  If `Environment.NewLine` was used instead then it would be handled correctly already.  However, I think this is a very unlikely case, but thought it worth mentioning.

The wikipedia article on [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) has some useful information on it's history (for example, IBM used `\025` to represent newline on it's mainframes according to the article).

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.NewLine` ensures that you use the platform specific notation for the new line. It may or may not be useful depending on what platforms you target. In the case if you target only iOS and Android, there is no difference.